# Prove or disprove a matrix $A$ is regular iff the multiplication with a base of $R^n$ is still a base of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let vectors $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ be a base for $R^n$. Then, I need to prove or disprove that, given a matrix $A$, such a matrix is regular if and only if  $u_1A,u_2A,...,u_nA$ is still a base for $R^n$.

So far, I thought about something like this. Let suppose we have a base $u_1,u_2$ for $R^2$. Then, if $u_1A,u_2A$ must be still a base, we should have that the system $\alpha (u_1A) + \beta (u_2A) = 0 $ if and only if $\alpha = \beta = 0$. So, in $A$ is regular, we can do the following (if I am not wrong) : $\alpha (u_1A) = -\beta (u_2A) \to \alpha u_1 = -\beta (u_2A)A^{-1} \to \alpha u_1 = -\beta u_2 \to \alpha u_1 +\beta u_2 = 0 $

If this is correct, since we already know $u_1,u_2$ is a base for $R^n$, than it is proved that if  $u_1A,u_2A,...,u_nA$ is still a base for $R^2$, then $A$ must be regular, and this can be extended to $R^n$ in general.

But how to prove or disprove the other way? And is the reasoning correct so far?

Comment: An invertible matrix

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Yes, your reasoning is good (it can be shortened a bit), and indeed you still have to prove the other direction. To do that, you can also prove that if $A$ is singular, then $u_1A, \,dots, u_nA$ is no longer a base (contraposition). Try this first for $n=2$ again. If $A$ is not invertible, there is a non-zero vector $z$ such that $zA = 0$. Now express $z$ in terms of the basis vectors $u_1, u_2$ and play around.

Comment: Hello @HansEngler, thank you very much! I will try and I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

To prove $A_{n\times n}^{-1} \text{ exists and $u_i,i=1,..,n$ is basis of $R^n$}  \iff \text{$u_iA_{n\times n} $ and $u_i ,i=1,..,n$  are bases of $R^n$}  $ :

For sufficiency , assume $A_{n\times n}^{-1}$ exists and
$\text{ $u_i,i=1,..,n$ is basis of $R^n$}$ . Let $U_{n \times n} =  
\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\:\\u_n \end{bmatrix} $ , we can write any $x\in R^n$ as
$x = cU $ for a unique $c\in R^{n}$. Then there exists a unique $k = cU A^{-1} U^{-1}\in R^n$ such that $x = k(UA)$ . This shows $n$ rows of $UA$ span $R^n$ .

For necessity , assume $\text{$u_iA_{n\times n} $ and $u_i ,i=1,..,n$  are bases of $R^n$}$ . We can write $U = QUA$ for unique invertible $Q\in R^{n\times n}$ . Then
$U^{-1}Q^{-1}U=A$ which is invertible .